# relationship between computer logical cores and nodejs threadpool

Tags: node.js, threadpool

I have read lots of articles on stackoverflow, but failed to find any references about relationship between computer`s logical cores and nodejs threadpool. I believe this is not the duplicated question.

I am using 2017 macbook pro which has 2physical core with 4threads(4 logical cores)

and I believe that nodejs uses threadpool size of 4 (reference with libuv) when doing heavy stuffs such as pbkdf2(function inside of crypto module), i/o operations.

my question is that, what is the relationship between computer's thread size and nodejs's threadpool size?

actually I have never thought about the computer's thread.

it may sound crazy but so far I believed computer only has physical core, and if application such as nodejs instance supports thread pool(in this case thread pool size of 4 by default), then computer can utilize multi-threading.

so what exactly is the relationship between those two?

do I have to change THREADPOOL_SIZE to number of computer's logical core to maximize the performance..?

Comment: You can probably answer most of those questions by studying [this source file](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/deps/uv/src/threadpool.c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

node.js does not dynamically adjust the threadpool size based on the CPUs or logical CPUs that are present.  It has a preset value (4) unless you customize it.

Because the threadpool is often used for blocking operations such as disk I/O, it's not necessarily true that an optimal value for the thread pool size is the number of logical CPUs you have (unlike the typical recommendation for clustering).

Instead, it would likely depend upon which specific types of operations you most want to optimize for and exactly how you're using those operations.  For example, it probably doesn't really help you a lot to make more and more parallel disk operations that are all trying to access the same physical disk because there's only one position the read/write head can move at a time so having lots of parallel operations all contending for the same read/write head may not speed things up (could even make things slower).

If you have a specific operation you're trying to optimize for, then your best bet is to create a reproducible benchmark test and then time it with several different sizes for the thread pool.

As was pointed out in a comment, you can study some of the relevant thread pool code [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/deps/uv/src/threadpool.c).

Comment: thanks for your detailed explanation.it depnds on the situation. this additional question may sound a bit odd. if my computer has logical core size of four, and imagine if libuv threadpool size is 8 by default. and there are blocking tasks. so in this case, can't my computer uses all those 8 threads?

Comment: as I mentioned in my question, I didn't know about the concept of logical cores in computer. I knew that if nodejs instance supports thread pool, then computer can utilize it.

Comment: if computer has 2 physical core, and 4 logical cores. it already supports multi-threading, right?

Comment: but if node instance doesn't support thread-pool, then no matter how computer has a lot of logical cores, they cannot use them?

Comment: @jwkoo - The thread pool is NOT used for running your Javascript.  That is still single threaded in node.js (except for the [experimental worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) in node v11.  The thread pool is used internally by libuv for some native code operations (such as disk I/O) as a means of taking a synchronous operation and presenting an asynchronous interface to your Javascript.

Comment: Some processors offer hyperthreads which make the processor appear to have double the number of cores that it actually has.  These are called logical cores.  For example, the i9-9900k has 8 physical cores, but because of hyperthreading, it presents 16 logical cores.  An OS can treat the processor as if it has 16 actual cores.  Depending upon the operation, hyperthreading can improve performance up to 10-15%, mostly because the CPU is more efficient with time slicing the hyperthreads in hardware than the OS is in software as there are still the same number of actual physical cores to run code.

Comment: appreciate for your answer. but I cannot understand what you've mentioned "The thread pool is NOT used for running your Javascript. That is still single threaded in node.js " isn`t thread pool multi thread, using 4 threads?

Comment: @jwkoo - I will repeat.  The thread pool is used internally by the native code portion of node.js to implement things like asynchronous file I/O functions.  It is NOT used to run your Javascript directly.  TheJavascript still runs your Javascript as single threaded.  So, if you start four asynchronous file operations (say you're reading bytes from four separate files), then the fs library built into node.js will use the thread pool to start four native code OS file operations.  But, your Javascript is just waiting for the file I/O results and will run again when a callback gets called.